# Select Distinct Not working in Spring with DSL Context

Tags: sql, spring, jooq

I have the ff. code.

```
 @Override
    public Optional<TransactionJournalRecord> findByReferenceNumber(final String referenceNumber) {
        return this.dsl
            .select(TRANSACTION_JOURNAL.fields())
            .distinctOn(TRANSACTION_JOURNAL.CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
            .from(TRANSACTION_JOURNAL)
            .where(TRANSACTION_JOURNAL.REFERENCE_NUMBER.eq(referenceNumber))
            .fetchOptionalInto(TransactionJournalRecord.class);
    }
```

All I want it to do is to query a specific reference number but only getting the first distinct ref. no.  as I want other duplicate transactions with the same ref no and customer number to be processed later on.

But I kept getting this error of

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Access database using jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [select distinct on (`transaction_journal`.`customer_number`) `transaction_journal`.`id`, `transaction_journal`.`reference_number`, `transaction_journal`.`future_dated_transaction_id`, `transaction_journal`.`send_money_type_id`, `transaction_journal`.`source_account_number`, `transaction_journal`.`source_account_type`, `transaction_journal`.`customer_number`, `transaction_journal`.`request_id`, `transaction_journal`.`destination_account_number`, `transaction_journal`.`destination_account_type`, `transaction_journal`.`destination_validation`, `transaction_journal`.`transfer_schedule_type`, `transaction_journal`.`currency_id`, `transaction_journal`.`amount`, `transaction_journal`.`service_fee`, `transaction_journal`.`transaction_date`, `transaction_journal`.`posting_date`, `transaction_journal`.`status`, `transaction_journal`.`remarks`, `transaction_journal`.`created_date`, `transaction_journal`.`updated_date`, `transaction_journal`.`source_account_name`, `transaction_journal`.`username`, `transaction_journal`.`reason`, `transaction_journal`.`card_number`, `transaction_journal`.`status_remarks`, `transaction_journal`.`creditor_bank_code`, `transaction_journal`.`creditor_details`, `transaction_journal`.`mobile_number`, `transaction_journal`.`address`, `transaction_journal`.`channel_id`, `transaction_journal`.`system`, `transaction_journal`.`purpose_of_transaction`, `transaction_journal`.`esb_posted_date`, `transaction_journal`.`currency_id_destination`, `transaction_journal`.`gl_pa_status`, `transaction_journal`.`gl_sf_status`, `transaction_journal`.`gl_status_remarks`, `transaction_journal`.`email_address`, `transaction_journal`.`exchange_rate`, `transaction_journal`.`contact_type`, `transaction_journal`.`contact_value`, `transaction_journal`.`is_validated` from `transaction_journal` where `transaction_journal`.`reference_number` = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on (`transaction_journal`.`customer_number`) `transaction_journal`.`id`, `transa' at line 1
    at org.jooq_3.11.12.MYSQL_8_0.debug(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If you take the SQL statement from your exception, are you able to execute the statement in its raw form? To me it seems a comma is missing between the two statements `(transaction_journal.customer_number) transaction_journal.id`

Comment: Oh, about that comma thing, I updated the post since it apparently changed the format when i made it a quote of sort.

BTW, I tried executing the sql query produced by spring, and got the same error inside MySQL workbench. Is there something I need to update to change version for this to work or this is a bug in my code?. Im quite not familiar as to why it didnt work as the DSL context seems to support it.

Comment: What if instead of using `.Select` and then `.DistinctOn`, you use `. selectDistinct(TRANSACTION_JOURNAL.fields()).asList()` ? Would that work?

Comment: didnt work, .asList() errors out.

Comment: How would you write the query in plain SQL that you execute in the workbench?

Comment: i have no idea, hahaha. this is my first time using distinct to do what I am trying to do. But for some reason

.groupBy(TRANSACTION_JOURNAL.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,TRANSACTION_JOURNAL.SEND_MONEY_TYPE_ID)

seems to work fine as I am able to retrieve unique transactions only and have the other duplicate be transacted later on. I Kinda dont know whats the difference between the two yet, but what I am aiming is to make it work with distinct since thats is what I know I should use for my use case.

Comment: GroupBy is, in your case, probably a more 'correct' way for you to accomplish your expected result.

Comment: really?, ok. I may really need to read the difference between the two I guess. Though if any, distinct will do the job too right?. Its just that I want it to make it work in distinct too since I may be needing this to work in the future with distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using `DISTINCT ON`

You're not using `DISTINCT`, you're using `DISTINCT ON`, which is a PostgreSQL vendor specific SQL feature. [In newer versions of jOOQ, `DISTINCT ON` is being emulated using window functions for other dialects](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/09/using-distinct-on-in-non-postgresql-databases/), so you might want to upgrade.

You'll still need an `ORDER BY` clause for `DISTINCT ON` to work. It's a bit of an esoteric PostgreSQL invention, adding to the confusion of [the logical order of operations in SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/).

#### Using `LIMIT`

While what you want to do is possible with `DISTINCT ON`, it seems overly complicated. Here's a much simpler way to solve your problem, producing an arbitrary record, or optionally, if you uncomment the `ORDER BY` clause, the first/last record given some ordering:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM transaction_journal
WHERE transaction_journal.reference_number = :referenceNumber
-- ORDER BY something
LIMIT 1
```

With jOOQ:

```java
@Override
public Optional<TransactionJournalRecord> findByReferenceNumber(
    final String referenceNumber
) {
    return this.dsl
        .selectFrom(TRANSACTION_JOURNAL)
        .where(TRANSACTION_JOURNAL.REFERENCE_NUMBER.eq(referenceNumber))
        // .orderBy(something)
        .limit(1)
        .fetchOptional();
}
```

#### Using `GROUP BY`

Note that in MySQL, if [strict mode is turned off](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict), then the `GROUP BY` approach you've mentioned in your comments will also produce an *arbitrary* value for all non-`GROUP BY` columns, which is not correct standard SQL.

Unlike as with `DISTINCT ON` or `LIMIT`, you have no control over which value is being produced. As a matter of fact, you can't even be sure if two non-`GROUP BY` values belong to the same record. It is never a good idea to depend on this outdated, MySQL-specific behaviour.

#### Using `DISTINCT`

There is no way to solve this with `DISTINCT` only. If you don't have a unique constraint on your search criteria, then you will always get duplicates, which will throw an exception when using `fetchOptional()`, in jOOQ.

Comment: Hi, I havent tried this myself, but reading this made it a bit more clear now and would seem to work. I will try the recommendations in jooq the next time I encounter this as at the moment, I have promoted my changes with a groupby syntax that passed my testing so far. thanks alot for clearing it up. I just kind of knew somehow that I may be using distinct incorrectly, and this explains it well. great. ♥